# How to assign one object values to another .object using recordset

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, recordset

I have a set of values accessed via asp in csv format and the object name is object1 .

```
<OBJECT id='object1' classid=clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83 VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="/R.asp?subject=sarath">
    <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="True">
    <PARAM NAME="TextQualifier" VALUE="|">
</OBJECT>
```

I need to assign all the values to another object2 and i am using document.all.object1.recordset.

below method is not working for me . Any solution to assign values .

```
     document.all.objecj2.object = document.all.object1.object;
```

Thanks

Comment: IF you print the value for object1, what do you see? Can you step through the Chrome debugger?

Comment: values are    a,b,c   like that

Comment: What is `object2`? Is it also a recordset?

Answer (score 0):

If you code in VBScript, you need `Set` to assign an object to a variable.

I don*'t know, whether assigning (references to) the same recodset to different HTML elements makes sense. You may consider to research the [.Clone method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: its java script and document.all related to microsoft

Comment: @user1703145 - the you should (a) remove the spurious Basic tags (b) publish a decent definition for "not working for me"